# create adodb RecordSet with query

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

I would like to get a recordset in excel VBA by triggering a query stored in MsAccess.

The code works fine when I add a proper SQL query, but I would like to avoid to add the query to the code, I would like to use a query stored in MSACCESS.

```
sql = "select * from qryUploadData"
With RS
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open sql
End With
```

qryUploadData is the the name of the access query. If I put it into an SQL query as if it would be a table, it works fine, but it doesn't, if I try to open it directly. Is there any way to use it ?

Comment: Have you tried `sql = "qryUploadData"` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid to add the query to the code" - the query must be referenced to open a recordset.

Comment: @June7 - I think the OP means that instead of inserting the query code *itself* into the VBA, they want to just 'call' it by name - as the query code is already in Access. Almost like a stored procedure.

Comment: by "avoid to add the query to the code"  I mean not to add the SQL statement to the vba code. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, using quotes like "qryUploadData" answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think my earlier comment explains it, but in case it's a little vague, calling the name of the query as your sql command should cause the query to be run in Access. You should be able to just:

```
sql = "qryUploadData"
With RS
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open sql
End With
```